# Reading a register value into a C variable

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, cpu-registers

I remember seeing a way to use extended gcc inline assembly to read a register value and store it into a C variable.

I cannot though for the life of me remember how to form the asm statement.

Comment: And how do you know what is in EBX when your C code starts executing?

Comment: You can't know what value compiler-generated code will have stored in any register when your inline `asm` statement runs, so the value is usually meaningless, and you'd be much better off using a debugger to look at register values when stopped at a breakpoint.  It might make sense for a stack pointer, but there's [`__builtin_frame_address(0)`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html) to get a stack address (and IIRC, cause that function to make a full stack frame, even when `-fomit-frame-pointer` is enabled, like it is by default on x86.)

Comment: Closing as a duplicate of a new Q&A because the **highest-voted answer here is outdated (broken with clang, unsupported by GCC)**. (It still happens to work with GCC, at least in simple cases.)  An asm statement that does a `mov %%reg, %0` to an `"=r"(var)` output is safe, too, that answer is fine.

Answer (score 36):

Editor's note: **this way of using a local register-asm variable is [now documented by GCC as "not supported"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html)**.  It still usually happens to work on GCC, but breaks with clang.  (This wording in the documentation was added after this answer was posted, I think.)

The global fixed-register variable version has a large performance cost for 32-bit x86, which only has 7 GP-integer registers (not counting the stack pointer).  This would reduce that to 6.  Only consider this if you have a global variable that all of your code uses heavily.

---

Going in a different direction than other answers so far, since I'm not sure what you want.

[GCC Manual § 5.40 Variables in Specified Registers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gcc/Explicit-Reg-Vars.html)

> ```
> register int *foo asm ("a5");
> ```
>
> Here `a5` is the name of the register which should be used…
>
> Naturally the register name is cpu-dependent, but this is not a problem, since specific registers are most often useful with explicit assembler instructions (see [Extended Asm](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm)). Both of these things generally require that you conditionalize your program according to cpu type.
>
> Defining such a register variable does not reserve the register; it remains available for other uses in places where flow control determines the variable's value is not live.

[GCC Manual § 3.18 Options for Code Generation Conventions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#index-ffixed-1972)

> `-ffixed-`*reg*
>
> > Treat the register named *reg* as a fixed register; generated code should never refer to it (except perhaps as a stack pointer, frame pointer or in some other fixed role).

This can replicate Richard's answer in a simpler way,

```
int main() {
    register int i asm("ebx");
    return i + 1;
}
```

although this is rather meaningless, as you have no idea what's in the `ebx` register.

If you combined these two, compiling this with `gcc -ffixed-ebx`,

```
#include <stdio.h>
register int counter asm("ebx");
void check(int n) {
    if (!(n % 2 && n % 3 && n % 5)) counter++;
}
int main() {
    int i;
    counter = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) check(i);
    printf("%d Hamming numbers between 1 and 100\n", counter);
    return 0;
}
```

you can ensure that a C variable always uses resides in a register for speedy access and also will not get clobbered by other generated code.  (Handily, `ebx` is callee-save under usual x86 calling conventions, so even if it gets clobbered by calls to other functions compiled without `-ffixed-*`, it should get restored too.)

On the other hand, this definitely isn't portable, and usually isn't a performance benefit either, as you're restricting the compiler's freedom.

Comment: Quoting from the [current docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html) describing local registers *The only supported use for this feature is to specify registers for input and output operands when calling Extended asm*.  So putting `i` within main() like this is unsupported.  And to emphasize your point: x86 only has a limited number of registers.  Removing one from general use via global register variable might slow down other critical parts of your code. Some discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27369224/2189500).

Comment: I'd *highly* recommend *not* using a global register variable, except maybe in one `.c` file containing one function as a hack.  Expect a significant performance cost, especially on 32-bit x86.

Answer (score 24):

Here is a way to get ebx:

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    asm("\t movl %%ebx,%0" : "=r"(i));
    return i + 1;
}
```

The result:

```
main:
    subl    $4, %esp
    #APP
             movl %ebx,%eax
    #NO_APP
    incl    %eax
    addl    $4, %esp
    ret
```

---

Edit:

The "=r"(i) is an output constraint, telling the compiler that the first output (%0) is a register that should be placed in the variable "i". At this optimization level (-O5) the variable i never gets stored to memory, but is held in the eax register, which also happens to be the return value register.

Comment: I would use the `=rm` constraint rather than `=r`. The compiler's optimizer will attempt to choose the best path. If the inline assembler happened to be in a register starved situation `=r` may force it to generate less than optimal code. `=rm` would give the optimizer a chance to use a memory reference if it happened to be the best choice. In this simple example it won't be an issue, but if the code is in a more complex situation then giving options to the compiler could be beneficial.

Comment: @MichaelPetch How about "=b" and an empty template string?

Comment: Note that clang will typically pick memory if you use `"=rm"`, even if it actually needs the value in a register.  It will end up storing and reloading.  This is a longstanding missed-optimization in clang's inline asm support.  Using `"=b"(i)` should also work, just telling the compiler that the EBX holds the value of `i` after the asm statement.  You may want `asm volatile` if you use this in more than one place, otherwise the compiler can assume that the asm statement always produces the same output (because the input is  always the same: the empty set of inputs.)

Comment: -O5 optimization ? I've read O3 is the maximum ?

Comment: In my case there is `warning: implicit declaration of function 'asm'` followed by `error: expected ')' before ':' token`: https://godbolt.org/z/PbqsMocEn. Do I miss something? @IlanSchemoul Re: "-O5": to my knowledge "if N > 3, then N = 3". Hence, -O5 is -O3.

Comment: UPD. It seems that instead of `asm` one needs `__asm volatile`.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about gcc, but in VS this is how:

```
int data = 0;   
__asm
{
    mov ebx, 30
    mov data, ebx
}
cout<<data;
```

Essentially, I moved the data in `ebx` to your variable `data`.

Comment: x86-only, of course.  Microsoft's compilers for x64 and Itanium do not support inline assembly.

Comment: I think the assembly will get translated to
    mov ebx, 30
    mov dword ptr[data], ebx

Comment: Why not just `mov data, 30` ?

Answer (score 5):

This will move the stack pointer register into the sp variable.

```
intptr_t sp;
asm ("movl %%esp, %0" : "=r" (sp) );
```

Just replace 'esp' with the actual register you are interested in (but make sure not to lose the %%) and 'sp' with your variable.

Answer (score 2):

From the GCC docs itself: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void gav(){
        //rgv_t argv = get();
        register unsigned long long i asm("rax");
        register unsigned long long ii asm("rbx");
        printf("I`m gav - first arguman is: %s - 2th arguman is: %s\n", (char *)i, (char *)ii);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *test = "I`m main";
    char *test1 = "I`m main2";
    printf("0x%llx\n", (unsigned long long)&gav);
    asm("call %P0" : :"i"((unsigned long long)&gav), "a"(test), "b"(test1));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Quoting from the [current docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html) describing local register variables *The only supported use for this feature is to specify registers for input and output operands when calling Extended asm*.  So putting `i` and `ii` within gav() like this is unsupported.

Answer (score 2):

You can't know what value compiler-generated code will have stored in any register when your inline `asm` statement runs, so the value is usually meaningless, and you'd be much better off using a debugger to look at register values when stopped at a breakpoint.

That being said, if you're going to do this strange task, you might as well do it efficiently.

On some targets (like x86) you can use specific-register output constraints to tell the compiler *which* register an output will be in.  **Use a specific-register output constraint with an empty asm template** (zero instructions) to tell the compiler that your asm statement doesn't care about that register value on input, but afterward the given C variable will be in that register.

```
#include <stdint.h>

int foo() {
    uint64_t rax_value;           // type width determines register size
    asm("" : "=a"(rax_value));  // =letter determines which register (or partial reg)

    uint32_t ebx_value;
    asm("" : "=b"(ebx_value));

    uint16_t si_value;
    asm("" : "=S"(si_value) );

    uint8_t sil_value;  // x86-64 required to use the low 8 of a reg other than a-d
       // With -m32:  error: unsupported size for integer register
    asm("# Hi mom, my output constraint picked %0" : "=S"(sil_value) );

    return sil_value + ebx_value;
}
```

Compiled with [clang5.0 on Godbolt for x86-64](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMeFsgYisAag6yAwoIL4WBAHQIN2DgAYAguYsKCqgGapUEAJTqA7H0uqfqkbYA2ABYAfTtiJgAPEIA3JmVMDR5fFJSAejTVAgBPAAdMVQB3PHQCBFUsAkxiAFsFTEFVYkxgPB1q1UE8AC9E718mQRqIdS4ubi5VEFHx2QARJgmICOi4hLcXJJ8M9XmGTAIq4gqD6rqWBqKEPGRy5tb244gSVVymYgI8eKaWzctrFL%2BfSyLhhVSYABGq3iIkSsi8FhSg2GMwmU1R8whS0h0PWqk28OsAN8QIItACYK6sRhcIRSKGIwmaOmTPmAGUllS1rCNkkif0fKSAByUvAMakJLbbTKRIUBAC0wR%2BAEd/M10FlUH5BAUygUGKhCqohapUPZVEwfsBTXrjmVWBb5ehiT5kYyxnJVAAJPCqGqoGqkP3ZU0iAi5MOqNAsHQRWyvG4Aa0wGu4AFYzMyMXMOWMIF1xdzMLzCf8BT8CGIWJ0xRLYaNkji67Sie45tYpC5GNI01JSCxpGY%2B6hpJp%2BPxOqJxAU5LQ%2BwRB52u4mQLJ3AYggFZABOdwBbdBNNcIJBbcBbtSIJ9mp0MxmfuL0gjqR9wQge8LqRDrtwWAwKD/hASBoDUuRitU5CUCBYH7MQKDMGwGb3vYYpHG%2BEAQo%2BEIKO82TSHOpAgTUmD6AA8iwDB4VIBFYDUrDAPsj74M0yCfDEDSPpgkSYMgYaSNRfa2JgDCPgQxB4DeAldgh7DjrwjB4BCb6QF2qC5J8qAxtI8o6M68zACwIhyTwtC0KoOm6AwikaHMVkQpwvATvKpGyOZ9jscQEKoDq8rIq%2BU4SHQ0k9n2A5fsO0iygqSpKPRqhpgYZiJaoEC4IQLyzkGmgBjBHSzm4Y6Obw86Li4XYIJgTBYHBrikCuGYXlepA3u4SVcCCZhCkK7jbtutDblw7hBA%2B4VPtIr7vqQn7fqQv6ICAojhmGkEQNB4FwfQKbpRtwVSL2I1DmNMjtWZxRlKoUWKkEUYyfFiWJSV4VlaQFVVdUlC7U1N5cNuBh7j1plcHeQpmO4XABFwB0RS%2BQiTdNS51SAQRCgYx6g0E6OY0NF6yKFj7Po9M1zcTwE5etK1rbBIDAO4sikChDBoZQIQs2YH2kJho3YSwuH4X2REkQQ5GUUxmB0WwjGjcxPFsRxo1cTxfF8%2BQ%2BjCY%2BVCqtUVGyKjBgEfsbBlHQpC5M0MSkRCVAy8zrOUF03TdPstAZpu7hCrItA7iClAiCwWAoRc6CUPswAkUHkCmaQ95SWV0kkcARv0KbmDm5b1sQCzIRs9QACKsLENkIK0GYIIZlwtDI1wQrHluGMBLQlD4IIuTMFRnZCD0juYM7Ziu%2B7nvbt7EC%2B/79RBxAIdh/AkfR3Osdx4bSC0M9YkSXz0n0SgxkKUp8CqepeCaW%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%2BDBH7OVcvKGowR37Th4bgn%2B%2BNIpyiuqocRoCDDgLSlAxB9BYFmMQbIZBV8pGfXwQEJKR4gjl3USDOUQRhnUIJrDOhT1lwgDTLQP6aYBq0rIXSga55cG42JeNPR5LEYQwMGmWQmL2pmDTEEdwaYXYXi4Pg7BbKYbwzqdICV0q0WkA8l0TSSMgA%3D%3D%3D).  Notice that the 2 unused output values are optimized away, no `#APP` / `#NO_APP` compiler-generated asm-comment pairs (which switch the assembler out / into fast-parsing mode, or at least used to if that's no longer a thing).  This is because I didn't use `asm volatile`, and they have an output operand so they're not implicitly `volatile`.

```
foo():                                # @foo()
# BB#0:
    push    rbx
    #APP
    #NO_APP
    #DEBUG_VALUE: foo:ebx_value <- %EBX
    #APP
    # Hi mom, my output constraint picked %sil
    #NO_APP
    #DEBUG_VALUE: foo:sil_value <- %SIL
    movzx   eax, sil
    add     eax, ebx
    pop     rbx
    ret
                                    # -- End function
                                    # DW_AT_GNU_pubnames
                                    # DW_AT_external
```

Notice the compiler-generated code to add two outputs together, directly from the registers specified.  Also notice the push/pop of RBX, because RBX is a call-preserved register in the x86-64 System V calling convention.  (And basically all 32 and 64-bit x86 calling conventions).  But we've told the compiler that our asm statement writes a value there.  (Using an empty asm statement is kind of a hack; there's no syntax to directly tell the compiler we just want to read a register, because like I said you don't know what the compiler was doing with the registers when your asm statement is inserted.)

The compiler will treat your asm statement as if it actually *wrote* that register, so if it needs the value for later, it will have copied it to another register (or spilled to memory) when your asm statement "runs".

---

**The other [x86 register constraints](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html#Machine-Constraints) are `b` (bl/bx/ebx/rbx), `c` (.../rcx), `d` (.../rdx), `S` (sil/si/esi/rsi), `D` (.../rdi)**.  There is no specific constraint for bpl/bp/ebp/rbp, even though it's not special in functions without a frame pointer.  (Maybe because using it would make your code not compiler with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`.)

You can use `register uint64_t rbp_var asm ("rbp")`, in which case `asm("" : "=r" (rbp_var));`  guarantees that the `"=r"` constraint will pick `rbp`.  Similarly for r8-r15, which don't have any explicit constraints either.  On some architectures, like ARM, asm-register variables are the only way to specify which register you want for asm input/output constraints.  (And  note that **[asm constraints are the *only* supported use of `register asm` variables](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html#Local-Register-Variables)**; there's no guarantee that the variable's value will be in that register any other time.

---

**There's nothing to stop the compiler from placing these asm statements anywhere it wants within a function (or parent functions after inlining)**.  So you have no control over *where* you're sampling the value of a register.  `asm volatile` may avoid some reordering, but maybe only with respect to other `volatile` accesses.  You could check the compiler-generated asm to see if you got what you wanted, but beware that it might have been by chance and could break later.

**You can place an asm statement in the dependency chain for something else to control where the compiler places it**.  Use a `"+rm"` constraint to tell the compiler it modifies some other variable which is actually used for something that doesn't optimize away.

```
uint32_t ebx_value;
asm("" : "=b"(ebx_value), "+rm"(some_used_variable) );
```

where `some_used_variable` might be a return value from one function, and (after some processing) passed as an arg to another function.  Or computed in a loop, and will be returned as the function's return value.  In that case, the asm statement is guaranteed to come at some point after the end of the loop, and before any code that depends on the later value of that variable.

This will defeat optimizations like constant-propagation for that variable, though.  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm.  The compiler can't assume *anything* about the output value; it doesn't check that the `asm` statement has zero instructions.

---

**This doesn't work for some registers that gcc won't let you use as output operands or clobbers, e.g. the stack pointer.**

Reading the value into a C variable might make sense for a stack pointer, though, if your program does something special with stacks.

As an alternative to inline-asm, there's [`__builtin_frame_address(0)`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html) to get a stack address.  (But IIRC, cause that function to make a full stack frame, even when `-fomit-frame-pointer` is enabled, like it is by default on x86.)

Still, in many functions that's nearly free (and making a stack frame can be good for code-size, because of smaller addressing modes for RBP-relative than RSP-relative access to local variables).

Using a `mov` instruction in an `asm` statement would of course work, too.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) what you are looking for?

Syntax:

```
 asm ("fsinx %1,%0" : "=f" (result) : "f" (angle));
```

Comment: You do realize that's going to read one variable, compute the sine and then store the result in a second variable.

Comment: @Samuel: That was an example of the syntax only.

Comment: Downvoted because this is an example of how to use extended assembly in GCC, not how to get the value of a specific register into a specific variable, which is what the OP asked. By specifying the registers using `%0` and `%1`, GCC will choose the register in question on your behalf. There's no assurance it will choose the register you're hoping for.