# Accessing a register without using inline assembly with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, x86, inline-assembly

I want to read the stack pointer register value without writing inline assembly.The reason I want to do this is because I want to assign the stack pointer register value to an element of an array and I find it cumbersome to access an array using inline assembly. So I would want to do something like that.

```
register "rsp" long rsp_alias; <--- How do I achieve something like that in gcc?
long current_rsp_value[NUM_OF_THREADS];

current_rsp_value[tid] = rsp_alias;
```

Is there anything like that possible with gcc?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114163/reading-a-register-value-into-a-c-variable

Comment: Will taking the address of a local variable be good enough for your application?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's a shortcut:

```
register long rsp asm ("rsp");
```

Demo:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void foo(void)
{
    register long rsp asm ("rsp");
    printf("RSP: %lx\n", rsp);
}

int main()
{
    register long rsp asm ("rsp");
    printf("RSP: %lx\n", rsp);
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Gives:

```
 $ gdb ./a.out 
GNU gdb (Gentoo 7.2 p1) 7.2
...
Reading symbols from /home/user/tmp/a.out...done.
(gdb) break foo
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400538: file t.c, line 7.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/user/tmp/a.out 
RSP: 7fffffffdb90

Breakpoint 1, foo () at t.c:7
7       printf("RSP: %lx\n", rsp);
(gdb) info registers
....
rsp            0x7fffffffdb80   0x7fffffffdb80
....
(gdb) n
RSP: 7fffffffdb80
8   }
```

Taken from the [*Variables in Specified Registers*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Explicit-Reg-Vars.html) documentation.

Comment: Thanks Mat, this was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Isn't this just a shorthand for inline assembly? :-) I think the docs have moved to: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gcc/Explicit-Reg-Vars.html

Comment: how do i access  accumulator data ??

Comment: Woth noting GCC very explicitly does not support this. Pinning register is only supported for use in extended assembly: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.1.0/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html

Answer (score 9):

```
register const long rsp_alias asm volatile("rsp");
```

Comment: Christoph, where should the const be placed, before register or after it?

Comment: @MetallicPriest: between `register` and `long` would be the most "natural" way, and indeed, it's a good idea.

Comment: yup -- I've noticed compiler optimizing away the selected register, thats why I included volatile.

Comment: I get a syntax error with `volatile` there (gcc 4.3)

Comment: @Eric same, and ` warning: optimization may eliminate reads and/or writes to register variables [-Wvolatile-register-var]` if I move it to a syntatically valid position.