# x86 assembler cpuid output function parse result of registers

Tags: assembly, x86, fasm, cpuid

I make a fasm program with `cpuid` and the output is:

```
EAX -> 0x00000662
EBX -> 0x00000000
ECX -> 0x00000000
EDX -> 0x0383FBFF
```

I use `fprint` from `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` to show this output.

So I need to read all flags from `EAX`,... regs with some function to see all specifications.

This mean to read the bits from registers or to make one structure of `cpuid` output.

Can you give me one solution to do that ?

Comment: yeah just move from register to variables.  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Example%20of%20asm%20with%20clobbered%20asm%20reg (i am assuming you're using gcc)

Comment: No i use fasm assembly code . I make a format ELF format executable with use32 I take the with " _start: mov eax,0x01 cpuid...
I use fprint just to show the regs. I need a fasm solution to parse the output. Maybe is strange for you , but I need learning assembly.

Comment: What have you tried? This should be broken up into subproblems, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114163/reading-a-register-value-into-a-c-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not fasm, please take a look at how Linux kernel uses it (GNU asm):

```
static inline void native_cpuid(unsigned int *eax, unsigned int *ebx,
                                unsigned int *ecx, unsigned int *edx)
{
        /* ecx is often an input as well as an output. */
        asm volatile("cpuid"
            : "=a" (*eax),
              "=b" (*ebx),
              "=c" (*ecx),
              "=d" (*edx)
            : "0" (*eax), "2" (*ecx)
            : "memory");
}


/* Some CPUID calls want 'count' to be placed in ecx */
static inline void cpuid_count(unsigned int op, int count,
                               unsigned int *eax, unsigned int *ebx,
                               unsigned int *ecx, unsigned int *edx)
{
        *eax = op;
        *ecx = count;
        __cpuid(eax, ebx, ecx, edx);
}
```

Finally read all the registers into a struct:

```
struct cpuid_regs {
        u32 eax, ebx, ecx, edx;
};

static void cpuid_smp_cpuid(void *cmd_block)
{
        struct cpuid_regs *cmd = (struct cpuid_regs *)cmd_block;

        cpuid_count(cmd->eax, cmd->ecx,
                    &cmd->eax, &cmd->ebx, &cmd->ecx, &cmd->edx);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my very old [kernel project](https://github.com/bmarcot/kemerald), and with GCC assembly inline:

```
#define CPUID(VALUE, EAX, EBX, ECX, EDX)                            \
  __asm__ __volatile__ ("   cpuid                   \n\t"           \
                    "       movl    %%eax, %0       \n\t"           \
                    "       movl    %%ebx, %1       \n\t"           \
                    "       movl    %%ecx, %2       \n\t"           \
                    "       movl    %%edx, %3"                      \
                    : "=m" (*EAX), "=m" (*EBX), "=m" (*ECX), "=m" (*EDX) \
                    : "a" (VALUE)                                   \
                    : "%ebx", "%ecx", "%edx"                        \
                    );
```

By the way, I am not sure that what you're looking for...