# Global register variables in gcc

Tags: c, gcc

Recently I was asked about global register variables in an interview.I messed up saying that any global variable will be stored in Data segment.But then i was asked about GCC.After interview i came  to conclusion that gcc supports global register variables.

```
#include<stdio.h>

register int var asm("ebx");  //storing global variable in register explicitly

int main(void)
{
.......
}
```

Here is link 
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Global-Reg-Vars.html#Global-Reg-Vars

But now i am confused about its **lifetime and scope** and whether it will work as normal global variable or as register variable? Also is there any method or some **command on gcc** so that we will be sure that compiler will not simply ignore `register` keyword and will be stored in actual register?

Comment: Can't you just try it out through debugger?

Comment: @MrSykkox:Could you help me out in this? also could you please provide answer to my 1st question? i will be thankful.

Comment: I'm not sure about the lifetime, but about testing it out. You compile with debug flag ( -g ) if you are using gdb ( -ggdb ). In your main code set var = something. Set break point before exit. And print the register value ( info register ebx ).

Comment: It's a global variable. The use of `register` changes neither lifetime nor scope. Do you really want to tie up EBX like this? You must realise that this is not functionality that would commonly be used.

Comment: You shouldn't even want to use a global register variable. In a register-impoverished environment like an Intel x86 computer, the compiler has better uses for registers than a global variable. In register-rich environments, the compiler can still probably make better use of registers rather than using one for a global. It is hard to conceive of a program where a single global variable will be used so intensely that it makes sense to have it stored in a register. And register is best left out of code in general, like you don't use `auto` either; the compilers know what to do better than you do.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:I am not sticking to EBX only.Just used as example shown here https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/linux-system-programming/0596009585/apas14.html

Comment: x86 registers are in short supply. You really don't want to tie them up like that. Why do you think it is a good idea to do this?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: As i have already written i was asked this question in an interview :) I never used it.I am just curious about its use and benefits.

Comment: Also, note that [C++11 has deprecated `register`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618008/register-keyword-c-11). C does not slavishly follow C++ but the writing is on the wall. Don't use `auto` in C; don't use `register` in new C code (and you can pretty much safely remove it in old C code). Using `register` for a global variable ties you to a specific C compiler, and has essentially no benefit. Remember, `register` is a hint to the compiler, not a command; the compiler may do as it pleases with your hint. Using `register` does stop you taking the address of the variable, but that's all.

Comment: If your interviewers are trying to trick you with questions about bizarre gcc extensions then you probably don't want to work with these people anyway!

Comment: The variable is not really global in the usual sense: for example two threads will see totally different values for the same variable, since each has a private `ebx`, so in that sense they are a bit closer to global thread-local vars.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a number of people have pointed out, reserving a register globally is generally a bad idea.  I believe the original intent here was (from the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Explicit-Reg-Vars.html#Explicit-Reg-Vars)):

> This may be useful in programs such as programming language
>   interpreters that have a couple of global variables that are accessed
>   very often.

Whether this is really useful, or just ends up making things worse can probably only be determined for specific cases.  In your case (interview question), that isn't really important.

The scope of a declaration like this is everything that sees the declaration, just as you would expect with any global declaration.

However, implementation is a bit tricky.  Again, quoting from the docs:

> Defining a global register variable in a certain register reserves
>   that register entirely for this use, **at least within the current
>   compilation**. The register is not allocated for any other purpose in
>   the functions in the current compilation, and is not saved and
>   restored by these functions.

So, all code that is COMPILED using that declaration will reserve the register for that use.  However, if you LINK to other code that was not compiled with this reservation, it will not be reserved for that purpose.

The docs give an excellent example with qsort.  If your code is compiled with this declaration, and then it calls qsort from the c runtime (which presumably isn't compiled with this declaration), and then qsort calls back into your code (for the compare function), the callback can't be sure that qsort doesn't stomp on the register before calling your compare function.

How can this ever work if calling any library function can stomp on the register?  Again from the docs:

> Choose a register that is normally saved and restored by function
>   calls on your machine, so that library routines will not clobber it.

Even at that:

> It is not safe to access the global register variables from signal
>   handlers, or from more than one thread of control, because the system
>   library routines may temporarily use the register for other things
>   (unless you recompile them specially for the task at hand).

As for the last part of your question:

> compiler will not simply ignore register keyword and will be stored in
>   actual register

I'm not sure what you mean.  If (somehow) the compiler ignored the `asm("ebx")`, then it would NOT be stored in a register.  The whole point of using this is to ensure that `var` is stored in the actual ebx register.