# How to read a specific register value on AM335X

Tags: arm, beagleboneblack

I want to get the unique serial number from Beaglebone Black. AM335X Reference Manual 9.3.1.25 tells me that I should be able to get the unique serial id from mac_id0_lo and mac_id0_hi registers. The offsets of these registers are 630h and 634h.

How can I read the values of these registers? I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114163/reading-a-register-value-into-a-c-variable) on stackoverflow, but it is not very helpful.

**UPDATE**

I finally got a python code working to read the mac_id0 and mac_id1 from beaglebone black.

```
from mmap import mmap
import struct

CONTROL_MODULE_OFFSET = 0x44E10000
CONTROL_MODULE_SIZE = 0x44E11FFF-CONTROL_MODULE_OFFSET
MAC_ID0_LO_OFFSET = 0x630
MAC_ID0_HI_OFFSET = 0x634
MAC_ID1_LO_OFFSET = 0x638
MAC_ID1_HI_OFFSET = 0x63C

def print_mac():
    file_handler = open("/dev/mem", "r+b")
    mem = mmap(file_handler.fileno(), CONTROL_MODULE_SIZE, offset=CONTROL_MODULE_OFFSET)

    mac_id0_lo_packed_reg = mem[MAC_ID0_LO_OFFSET:MAC_ID0_LO_OFFSET+4]
    mac_id0_hi_packed_reg = mem[MAC_ID0_HI_OFFSET:MAC_ID0_HI_OFFSET+4]

    mac_id1_lo_packed_reg = mem[MAC_ID1_LO_OFFSET:MAC_ID1_LO_OFFSET+4]
    mac_id1_hi_packed_reg = mem[MAC_ID1_HI_OFFSET:MAC_ID1_HI_OFFSET+4]

    mac_id0_lo = struct.unpack('<L', mac_id0_lo_packed_reg)[0]
    mac_id0_hi = struct.unpack('<L', mac_id0_hi_packed_reg)[0]
    mac_id0_bytes = [None]*6
    mac_id0_bytes[0] = (mac_id0_lo & 0xff00) >> 8 #byte 0
    mac_id0_bytes[1] = (mac_id0_lo & 0x00ff) #byte 1
    mac_id0_bytes[2] = (mac_id0_hi & 0xff000000) >> 24 #byte 2
    mac_id0_bytes[3] = (mac_id0_hi & 0x00ff0000) >> 16 #byte 3
    mac_id0_bytes[4] = (mac_id0_hi & 0x0000ff00) >> 8 #byte 4
    mac_id0_bytes[5] = (mac_id0_hi & 0x000000ff) #byte 4
    mac_address_id0 = 0
    for i, byte in enumerate(mac_id0_bytes):
        mac_address_id0 |= ((byte & 0xff) << (i*8))

    mac_id1_lo = struct.unpack('<L', mac_id1_lo_packed_reg)[0]
    mac_id1_hi = struct.unpack('<L', mac_id1_hi_packed_reg)[0]
    mac_id1_bytes = [None]*6
    mac_id1_bytes[0] = (mac_id1_lo & 0xff00) >> 8 #byte 0
    mac_id1_bytes[1] = (mac_id1_lo & 0x00ff) #byte 1
    mac_id1_bytes[2] = (mac_id1_hi & 0xff000000) >> 24 #byte 2
    mac_id1_bytes[3] = (mac_id1_hi & 0x00ff0000) >> 16 #byte 3
    mac_id1_bytes[4] = (mac_id1_hi & 0x0000ff00) >> 8 #byte 4
    mac_id1_bytes[5] = (mac_id1_hi & 0x000000ff) #byte 4
    mac_address_id1 = 0
    for i, byte in enumerate(mac_id1_bytes):
        mac_address_id1 |= ((byte & 0xff) << (i*8))

    print 'mac id0'
    print format(mac_address_id0, '08x')

    print 'mac id1'
    print format(mac_address_id1, '08x')

    if not file_handler.closed:
        file_handler.close()
    mem.close()
print_mac()
```

Comment: @AlexZielenski that's not the kind of register OP is asking baout.

Comment: What OS if any are you using?

Comment: @doron, I'm using debian wheezy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those registers must be memory mapped, so question is how you can figure out complete physical address and find a way to access that physical address.

From the TRM:

> The values read from Control Module (Base address 0x44E1_0000) 
>   MAC_ID0_LO register (Offset 0x630), MAC_ID0_HI register (Offset
>   0x634), MAC_ID1_LO register (Offset 0x638), and MAC_ID1_HI register
>   (Offset 0x63C) represent  unique MAC addresses assigned to each AM335x
>   device.  The values in these registers are programmed into each AM335x
>   device by TI and can not be changed.

May be you can use [devmem2](http://www.lartmaker.nl/lartware/port/devmem2.c) like `devmem2 0x44e10630` however that may depend on Linux not having `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM`. Worse you may need to write a small kernel driver to access those memory areas.

Comment: You can try using a ready purpose-built system like this project: https://github.com/kaiwan/device-memory-readwrite

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by auselen I just tried to read the value in the main counter register of the high precision timer chip by doing `devmem2 0xfed000f0` and it worked despite `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM` is set, due to the fact that it's non-RAM and thus readable/writable in userspace.