# How I can get the value of int 0x16?

Tags: c, gnu-assembler

I have this inline assembler on my C code:

```
asm volatile ("mov %ah, 01\n"
              "int $0x16\n");
```

This code is a assembler version of `getch()`

It works, but now I want to get the value that returned this inline assembler (specifically I want to know the key that returns the interruption 16h).

How I can do it?

Edit: I'm making MS-DOS COM files using C and DosBox. Currently everything is working fine, except for the problem that I'm having right now.

Full code:

```
asm (".code16gcc\n"
     "call  dosmain\n"
     "mov   $0x4C,%ah\n"
     "int   $0x21\n");

static void print(char *string)
{
    asm volatile ("mov   $0x09, %%ah\n"
                  "int   $0x21\n"
                  : /* no output */
                  : "d"(string)
                  : "ah");
}

int dosmain(void)
{

    int a;
    asm volatile ("mov %%ah, 0\n"
                  "int $0x16\n"
                   : "=r"(a));

    print(a);
    print("Hello, World!\n$");
    return 0;
}
```

But causes a nice "buffer overflow?"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114163/reading-a-register-value-into-a-c-variable Like this?

Comment: What environment are you coding for, and what compiler are you using?

Comment: @duskwuff gcc under WSL

Comment: @138 thanks, but it doesn't worked. Any examples with my actual code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a toolchain problem.

The version of GCC you are using is a 32-bit compiler. Inserting the `asm(".code16gcc")` directive at the top changes the behavior of the assembler to allow 32-bit instructions to be used, but *does not* make GCC aware of the segmented memory model used in real mode. Combined with the (unknown, and probably incorrect) steps you are using to generate a `.com` binary, the result will be a non-working executable.

If you want to build DOS executables, use a toolchain which targets this environment, such as [OpenWatcom](http://www.openwatcom.org/).